# How can I create a square gradient in CSS to use a mask

Tags: html, css, webkit, gradient, linear-gradients

Using the `backdrop-filter` css parameter, you can blur the background of a div:

```css
#image {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/527/300/300.jpg?hmac=wk333ApmV6eJV8v2QbKrGH1urFbDlb2bEt92dWS5Yno);
}

#image div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <div>Blurred</div>
</div>
```

Using the `mask-image` parameter, you can add a gradient mask to fade out an edge:

```css
#image {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/527/300/300.jpg?hmac=wk333ApmV6eJV8v2QbKrGH1urFbDlb2bEt92dWS5Yno);
}

#image div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 70%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <div>Blurred</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to create a blurred square with these faded edges, that can handle being resized? Or a way to receive the same effect with another method?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a black png to do so like this one
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/WX_circle_black.png

```css
#image {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/527/300/300.jpg?hmac=wk333ApmV6eJV8v2QbKrGH1urFbDlb2bEt92dWS5Yno);
}

#image div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  width: 150px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
  height: 150px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(12px);
  mask-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/WX_circle_black.png');
  -webkit-mask-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/76/WX_circle_black.png');
-webkit-mask-size: cover;

}
```

```html
<div id="image">
  <div>Blurred</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This might be what I end up going with, but I was hoping there would be a way to make it work with dynamically resizable elements (sorry, I should've specified in the question).

Answer (score 1):

Use the `box-shadow` inside of an element (`inset`).

Syntax:
`<inset> <x-offset> <y-offset> <blur-radius> <spread-radius> <color>`

In this example I just used blue for demonstration purpose.

```css
#image {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background: url(https://i.picsum.photos/id/527/300/300.jpg?hmac=wk333ApmV6eJV8v2QbKrGH1urFbDlb2bEt92dWS5Yno);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 50px 10px rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<div id="image">
</div>
```

Comment: How would I use this with the blur effect (see my code snippets) though?